# Why cplex gives me an error "name j2 does not exist"?

Tags: indexing, constraints, cplex

I wrote the following code in cplex but it gives me an error like "name j2 does not exist"

```
subject to {

   forall (r in R)

     forall (j1, j2 in J)//con j1 =!da j2
    
         (T[j2][r] >= C[j1] - bigM*(1-Q[j1][j2][r]) - bigM*(2-z[j1][r]-z[j2][r]));
         
         (T[j1][r] >= C[j2] - bigM*Q[j1][j2][r] - bigM*(2-z[j1][r]-z[j2][r]));
}
```

Can you help me understand where am I wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

can you try to change

```
forall (j1, j2 in J)//con j1 =!da j2

     (T[j2][r] >= C[j1] - bigM*(1-Q[j1][j2][r]) - bigM*(2-z[j1][r]-z[j2][r]));
     
     (T[j1][r] >= C[j2] - bigM*Q[j1][j2][r] - bigM*(2-z[j1][r]-z[j2][r]));
```

into

```
forall (j1, j2 in J)//con j1 =!da j2

{

     (T[j2][r] >= C[j1] - bigM*(1-Q[j1][j2][r]) - bigM*(2-z[j1][r]-z[j2][r]));
     
     (T[j1][r] >= C[j2] - bigM*Q[j1][j2][r] - bigM*(2-z[j1][r]-z[j2][r]));

}
```

?

Comment: I tried and it works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. NB: instead of bigM you could use logical constraints. Example : https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoological.mod

Comment: Glad that Alex's solution works. This is a type of error I have seen several times from people who have learnt to program in Python first and forget the braces/brackets around blocks of code.